# Multiple iterations through a file structure (C#)

Tags: c#, file-structure

I am writing a program which iterates through the file system multiple times using simple loops and recursion.

The problem is that, because I am iterating through multiple times, it is taking a long time because (I guess) the hard drive can only work at a certain pace.

Is there any way to optimize this process? Maybe by iterating though once, saving all the relevant information in a collection and then referring to the collection when I need to?

I know I can cache my results like this but I have absolutely no idea how to go about it.

Edit:

There are three main pieces of information I am trying to obtain from a given directory:

- The size of the directory (the sum of the size of each file within that directory)
- The number of files within the directory
- The number of folders within the directory

All of the above includes sub-directories too. Currently, I am performing an iteration of a given directory to obtain each piece of information, i.e. three iterations per directory.

My output is basically a spreadsheet which looks like this:

[image: Program Output]

Comment: surely there is a way, show your code with your multiple, consecutive iterations

Comment: It looks like you know the right answer - Cache your results, and refer to those instead of the disk

Comment: that is a possible solution BUT you don't provide enough information (what exactly are you doing with the information ? Does it need to current with all changes or is it ok to for example a minute behing ? or are you "polling" the filesystem to see what changed ?)... please show some source code...

Comment: Time doesn't matter in my application. I am only doing comparisons between files and a list of paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve performance, you could access the Master File Table (MFT) of the NTFS file system directly. There is a excellent code sample on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c1550294-d121-4511-ac32-31551497f64e) social forum.
It seems that accessing the MFT is about 10x faster than enumerating the file system using FindFirst/FindNext file.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes anything you can do to minimize hard drive I/O will improve the performance. I would also suggest putting in a Stopwatch and measure the time it takes so you can get a sense of how your improvements are affecting the speed.